# How to add custom fonts in Wordpress site

Tags: css, fonts

I have to use a font for a website which I can't find in Typekit and can't upload to Fontsquirrel. So I can't make a webkit. I tried to embed the font with CSS and `@font-face`, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Oz Handicraft";
    src: url(localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_child/ozHandicraft.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Liberation Regular";
    src: url(public_html/your-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_child/liberationRegular.tff);
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Liberation Bold";
    src: url(public_html/your-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_child/liberationBold.tff);
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Liberation Bold Italic";
    src: url(public_html/your-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_child/liberationBoldItalic.tff);
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Liberation Italic";
    src: url(public_html/your-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen_child/liberationItalic.tff);
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I finally found the problem and it seems like it's working now.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Oz Handicraft";
    src: url(fonts/ozHandicraft.otf);
```

My mistake was that I wrote the complete path in the url and not the path from the stylesheet (which is located in the theme-folder)

Comment: is this the right one? I've found this link : https://typekit.com/fonts/liberation-sans

Comment: No, I'm looking for the font Oz Handicraft. @SerkanAlgur

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. Can you try this config with fontsquirrel. This will generate a base64 css file with oz handicraft file. (added as answer)

Comment: @SerkanAlgur Already tried it. but fontSquirrel doesn't know the Oz Handicraft font or blocked it somehow

Comment: Your URLs are incorrect. They're a path to the file, not a URL

Comment: @JacobPeattie And what URL should I use then?

Answer (score 0):

This is the fontsquirrel config data. save as generator_config.txt and upload with your font file. select expert mode.

```
# Font Squirrel Font-face Generator Configuration File
# Upload this file to the generator to recreate the settings
# you used to create these fonts.

{"mode":"expert","formats":["ttf"],"tt_instructor":"ttfautohint","fix_gasp":"xy","fix_vertical_metrics":"Y","metrics_ascent":"","metrics_descent":"","metrics_linegap":"","add_spaces":"Y","add_hyphens":"Y","fallback":"none","fallback_custom":"100","webonly":"Y","options_subset":"basic","subset_range":["lowercase","uppercase","currency","malagasy","turkish"],"subset_custom":"","subset_custom_range":"","subset_ot_features":"all","subset_ot_features_list":"","base64":"Y","style_link":"Y","css_stylesheet":"stylesheet.css","filename_suffix":"","emsquare":"2048","spacing_adjustment":"0","rememberme":"Y"}
```

Comment: I can't upload the font Oz Handicraft because it seems to be clocked by FontSquirrel.

Comment: I am not sure if download link share is against to rules but i converted oz Handicraft (BT one) to webfont with fontsquirrel. You can view what zip files includes and download. https://yadi.sk/d/B--UDFN33Qx6S8

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried it again. Do I have to put the font name under double quotes? Or shouldn't I write the code in style.css or write the h1 code in the additional CSS?

Comment: If you include base64 font file css to your page try ``h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: 'ozhandicraft_btroman';}``