# Custom font isn't active on all PCs

Tags: css, fonts

I already asked [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289461/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress-site) question about how to add a custom font and I finally found a way so that the font is shown on my own Notebook.

What I found out today is, that this specific custom font (and maybe another font too, but it is a text-font so I don't see the difference) isn't active on a PC, at my school. (It's about [this](http://www.stpeter.bvoe.at/) homepage, look at the title font, which should be Oz Handicraft; I also placed a image at the end, so you can see the font how it should look like).

This is how I embedded the font:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Oz;
    src: url("fonts/ozHandicraft.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: Liberation;
    src: url("fonts/liberation.ttf");
     font-weight: normal;
}
```

I already thought of some possible mistakes, but don't know how I could check of they are the actual mistake.

- The font isn't actually embedded and the font can only be displayed on computers where the Oz Handicraft is installed
- I had problems uploading the font to "font squirrel webkit" because it was blocked. Maybe the font is blocked on wordpress too and can only be displayed on computers where the font is installed

How can I check these mistakes if they are true, what can be other mistakes I made?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a solution for you - but I would recommend using https://fonts.google.com/ instead of hosting your own. It's the best approach for custom fonts on websites that'll work on the widest scope of browsers, with no licensing issues.

Comment: The problem is different browsers support different font types. If your fonts are not available from Google, try the Font Squirrel Webfont Generator - https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator - you can upload your fonts, tell it which character sets to include, and it will give you the various files (and CSS) you need to make it work across most browsers.

Comment: You might need a `.eot` format

Comment: @WebElaine  Font Squirrel doesn't work, as I already said. I couldn't find the font on google fonts either. I tested it with different browsers and it worked on both Chrome and Firefox. It seems to differ from device to device.

Comment: Different browsers use/and are compatible with different [font formats](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp). So having just one font format for each font may not be enough.

Comment: You declare @font-face: oz, but call it in your css as font-family: Oz Handicraft;

Comment: Alternatives to FontSquirrel that will give you the necessary other file formats: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/13851-alternatives-to-the-font-squirrel-webfont-generator/

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your CSS Declarations on your page.

If you change the line 152 on your style.css from "font-family: Oz Handicraft;' (and anyplace else you're using it) to:

```
    h1 {
    font-family: Oz;
    }
```

since in your code, you have this.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Oz;
    src: url("fonts/ozHandicraft.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

you declare it as such.  If you make this change, it works fine on my screen, and I don't have this font installed on my desktop.

Other solution is to simply update your @font-face and put this instead:

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: Oz Handicraft;
    src: url("fonts/ozHandicraft.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
}
```